# ClassNotFoundException with java agent (-javaagent:jarpath)

Tags: java, jboss, classloader, jboss7.x, agent

The root of my problem is that I'm trying to use the SizeOf [sourceforge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sizeof/) from a web application deployed on JBoss AS7 and getting a `ClassNotFoundException` for `net.sourceforge.sizeof.SizeOf`. I added `-javaagent:/path_to_jar/SizeOf.jar` to the server's `JAVA_OPTS` and see the `System.out.println` from the premain method on server startup (JAVAGENT: call premain instrumentation for class SizeOf). However, when I try to call `SizeOf.sizeOf(obj)` from my servlet's doGet method, the application fails with the aforementioned `ClassNotFoundException`.

If anyone can tell me how to get this working with JBoss AS7, that would be helpful (I have it working in an Eclipse run configuration -- the equivalent of running from the command line). What I would really like to do, above and beyond that, is to understand how classloading works for Java Agents. The best documentation I've been able to find is in [the offical JVM docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html), and that's pretty sparse. All it says about classloading is that the Premain-Class will be loaded by the system classloader. I saw a blog post that suggested that the jar didn't need to be placed on the classpath, since the -javaagent JVM argument would take care of that, so it would appear that I shouldn't have to add the SizeOf jar as a AS7 module. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to do the following:

- Create a module for agent: create folder modules/net/sourceforge/sizeof/main and add sizeof.jar and a module.xml
- Add module to boot config: add JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS="net.sourceforge.sizeof" to bin/standalone.conf
- Also in bin/standalone.conf, append -javaageent:../modules/net/sourceforge/sizeof/main/sizeof.jar to JAVA_OPTS