# NoClassDefException, need to add something in JBoss AS 7

Tags: configuration, jboss, osgi, javaagents

I installed a java agent on my jboss AS 7. But when I run the standalone.bat, it throw NoClassDefException. I find the troubleshooting guide of the agent which says "

> Also verify whether the application uses OSGi. If it does (as in JBoss
>   7), add **com.itko** to the system or bootstrap packages. The method for
>   adding **com.itko** is container-dependent, which makes it difficult to
>   provide specific instructions. However, it is typically a
>   configuration file with a property that specifies a list of packages
>   or a similar JVM argument."

Can you provide me the specific instruction of how to add it on JBoss AS 7?

Thanks

Comment: Also, stop messing around and get back to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring **org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra** within your standalone.xml for subsystem 'urn:jboss:domain:osgi'. You may have to create a module as well, and add that to your OSGI subsystem.

Here is a related question with similar answer(s):

[ClassNotFoundException with java agent (-javaagent:jarpath)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731471/classnotfoundexception-with-java-agent-javaagentjarpath)

Comment: Thank u for you help. First, I guess ClassNotFoundException and NoClassDefException are caused by different reasons. If their solutions are same, I will try the related question.